# Make a query where the colums are based on finding text from another table

Tags: sql-server, query

This is probably easier to explain with a toy example.

I have a MSSQL database with two tables. Firstly, I have table A, which has two columns: "Dish_name" and "Dish_ingredients". It looks something like this:

| Dish_name | Dish_ingredients |
| --- | --- |
| Strawberry cheesecake | Butter, wheat, cream cheese, sugar, blueberry jam |
| Beef stew | Beef, tomatoes, carrots, celery, canola oil, onions |
| Spaghetti carbonara | Pasta, eggs, heavy cream, pork belly, salt |
| Avocado toast | Toast, avocado |
| ... | ... |

The second table, Table B, lists all the ingredients I may find and whetehr they are dairy products, have gluten, etc.

| Ingredient | Is_dairy | Has_gluten |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Butter | 1 | 0 |
| Wheat | 0 | 1 |
| Cream cheese | 1 | 0 |
| Sugar | 0 | 0 |
| Blueberry jam | 0 | 0 |
| Beef | 0 | 0 |
| Tomatoes | 0 | 0 |
| Carrots | 0 | 0 |
| Celery | 0 | 0 |
| Canola oil | 0 | 0 |
| Onions | 0 | 0 |
| Pasta | 0 | 1 |
| Eggs | 0 | 0 |
| Heavy cream | 1 | 0 |
| Pork belly | 0 | 0 |
| Salt | 0 | 0 |
| Toast | 0 | 1 |
| Avocado | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Based on these two tables, I'm trying to make a table that tells me if my dishes are ok for lactose intolerant people so I can make a menu for my party. I throw a similar party every month and since I add more dishes and ingredients to my tables all the time, the query must be able to keep up without me going back and changing its structure every time. Case-sensitivity does not bother me, but I wouldn't rely on always having commas as separators in "Dish_ingredients".

Comment: Normalise your "dish" table properly, and the problem is trivially solved.

Comment: @mustaccio For the sake of the argument, assume the tables are fixed as shown and I don't have write privileges to the database

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: "*but I wouldn't rely on always having commas as separators in "Dish_ingredients"*" - Then what can we rely on?...It's not possible to answer your question without this bit of information.

Comment: @Peter Microsoft SQL 12.0

Comment: @J.D. That's why I'm having trouble with it. I know that the text of each ingredient will either be present or not without wierdness inside, so things as"where Dish_ingredients like '%cream cheese%'" should work just fine.

Comment: @Variax, I've updated the answer with  LIKE version.

Comment: @Variax "*so things as"where Dish_ingredients like '%cream cheese%'" should work just fine*" - Unfortunately no, a contains search will run you trouble when the word for an ingredient is a subset of another ingredient's word, such as `'%cream%'` which would match on both ingredients `'cream'` and incorrectly `'cream cheese'`. Unfortunately there's not a completely reliable way to solve your problem without fixing the source data (which ideally would be by normalizing it as mustaccio mentioned, or minimally defining all of the consistent separators between ingredients).

Comment: If you can't identify all of the possible separators yourself, then maybe some sort of application layer code with RegEx, or AI can help you do so. But that's outside the scope of this forum.

Answer (score 0):

When using SQL Server 2016 or later you can use STRING_SPLIT to get your ingredients per dish. You can then join that table and check if a dish has specific bit's on or off. For example this:

```
SELECT
         ta.Dish_name,
         tb.Ingredient,
         CAST(MAX(CAST(tb.Is_Dairy AS INT)) AS BIT) AS HasDairyIngredients,
         CAST(MAX(CAST(tb.Has_Gluten AS INT)) AS BIT) HasGlutenIngredients
FROM     TableA AS ta
         CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ta.Dish_Ingredients, ',') AS ss
         JOIN TableB AS tb ON tb.Ingredient = ss.value
GROUP BY ta.Dish_name,
         tb.Ingredient;
```

With this you can define for the dish if one of the ingredients has Dairy or Gluten ingredients.

Based on the remark of J.D. and the addition of Variax. You might want to use this:

```
SELECT
         ta.Dish_name,
         CAST(MAX(CAST(tb.Is_Dairy AS INT)) AS BIT) AS HasDairyIngredients,
         CAST(MAX(CAST(tb.Has_Gluten AS INT)) AS BIT) HasGlutenIngredients
FROM     @TableA AS ta
         LEFT JOIN @TableB AS tb ON ta.Dish_Ingredients LIKE CONCAT(
                                                                      '%',
                                                                      tb.Ingredient,
                                                                      '%'
                                                                   )
GROUP BY ta.Dish_name;
```

Comment: Please keep in mind OP stated "*but I wouldn't rely on always having commas as separators in "Dish_ingredients"*" which unfortunately makes the information they provided an incomplete problem and unsolvable.

Comment: FWIW, a contains search will run you trouble when the word for an ingredient is a subset of another ingredient's word, such as `'%cream%'` which would match on both ingredients `'cream'` and incorrectly `'cream cheese'`. I don't believe OP realized this issue when they made their suggestion in the comments.

Comment: Good addition indeed.